# tex4ht: Unicode representations of apostrophe in UTF-8 HTML source

Tags: unicode, tex4ht, apostrophe

If I compile a latex document with tex4ht (under Tex Live 2016 / Windows 10) using

```
htlatex "my_doc.tex" "xhtml,charset=utf-8,fn-in" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

the apostrophe character in LaTeX source, either U+2019 (’) or U+0027 ('), is rendered in HTML source as `&#x2019;` instead of just `’`.

Is it possible to fix this, maybe with a custom configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tex4ht` uses special file, `unicode.4hf`, to translate certain characters in the converted document to some other characters, or `XML` entities. Otherwise, they are written as `utf8` characters, when you use `-utf8` option for `tex4ht`.

This file is requested by `-c` option for `tex4ht` command, in your case it is `unihtf`. There are several version of `unicode.4hf` in the distribution, their locations are configured in the `tex4ht.env` file:

```
<unihtf>
i~/tex4ht.dir/texmf/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/!
i~/tex4ht.dir/texmf/tex4ht/ht-fonts/ascii/!
i~/tex4ht.dir/texmf/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/!
</unihtf>
```

the first located file is used. You can find which one in the command line output:

```
tex4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:36 kpathsea)
tex4ht -utf8 
  -cunihtf 
  sample.dvi 
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/html/charset/unicode.4hf)
```

when you open this file, you can see at the beginning:

```
'&#x003C;' '' '&#x003C;' '' 
'&#x003E;' '' '&#x003E;' '' 
'&#x0022;' '' '&#x0022;' '' 
'&#x2019;' '' '&#x2019;' '' 
'&#x0026;' '' '&#x0026;' ''
```

The character to be looked for is in the first field and it must be in the form of numerical `xml` entity. The output character is in the third field and it can be any string, in this case it is the same entity as in the source.

So, to output the apostrophe in the document, copy the `unicode.4hf` to your document's directory and remove the line

```
'&#x2019;' '' '&#x2019;' ''
```

Sample output:

```xml
<!--l. 7--><p class="noindent" >hello’ world’
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I modified the original `unicode.4hf` and it works. I'll have to remember this at every new installation of Tex Live.